# How can I define a mime type in nginx for tar.bz2 or tar.gz files?

Tags: nginx, mime-type

I tried adding these lines to mime.types:

```
application/x-gtar tar.gz tgz tar.bz2 tbz2 tbz;
application/x-bzip2 bz2;
application/x-gzip  gz;
```

But nginx reports "Content-Type: application/x-bzip2" for a tar.bz2 file. How can I fix it?

Additional question: what's the correct mime type for tar.bz2/tbz2 files? Different sources gave me all kinds of different answers: application/x-gtar, application/x-compressed-tar, application/x-bzip-compressed-tar, application/x-tar-bz2, application/x-bzip2, etc.
Same for tar.gz/tgz

Answer (score 3):

There's a disclaimer in `/etc/mime.types` file:

> Note: Compression schemes like "gzip", "bzip", and "compress" are not
>    actually "mime-types".  They are "encodings" and hence must *not* have
>    entries in this file to map their extensions.  The "mime-type" of an
>    encoded file refers to the type of data that has been encoded, not the
>   type of encoding.

This means that you should have `application/x-tar` to map tarballs instead of separate content-type for each compressing method.

You can safely copy it from `/etc/mime.types` for instance.

Comment: I don't have that note in /etc/mime.types, but I can see some logic in it. So that means *.tar.gz & co should probably be identified as application/x-tar. Still, that leaves 2 questions: 1. How to define the mime type in nginx? (Not all gz's are tars) and 2. What's the mime type of foo.gz? Is it necessary to extract the file to determine it?

Comment: @aditsu did you find an answer to this?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai not really, I just used `application/x-bzip2 bz2;` and `application/x-gzip  gz;`

Comment: Funny disclaimer. By that logic HTML is not a type because it's text.

Answer (score 1):

You probably can use the [HttpHeadersMoreModule](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpHeadersMoreModule) with some regular expression matching to override the `Content-Type` if the url ends with one of the extensions.

Comment: Hmm, I haven't tried it yet, and seems convoluted, but I guess it could work.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [conf/mime.types](http://pastebin.com/Mgm3udE6), it seems that nginx doesn't support this mime types.

Comment: That's why I'm trying to add them. But apparently it doesn't support dotted extensions.